# kivy text doesn't change in screen switching while the text variable has been successfully modified

Tags: python, android, ios, kivy, kivy-language

We are creating an app for book-reading with an already build API. Choosing kivy for creating a front-end GUI seems to be really nice :D

But there is a problem we can not fix. the showing text on different screens doesn't change in the app while the text variable has been successfully changed. that's quite confusing for us, we have used the StringProperty() but the problem remained the same. We can change the showing text while the button and the text label are both on the same screen without problem.

the idea is we want to change the showing title and content on the other screen while we click the different buttons, so we make the "Article_Titles_List_py" and "ArticleContent" variables,which change successfully with button-click. But somehow the showing text (article title and content) remained the same as the default value. does someone know what the problem is?

Here is our kv file :

```
WindowManager:
    HomepageWindow:
    ArticleTitleWindow:
    ArticleWindow:
    AutherWindow:


<HomepageWindow>:
    name: "Homepage"

    GridLayout:

        cols:1

        Label:
        ###This showing text can be change successfully with trigger button in the same screen###
            text: root.HomepageContent

        GridLayout :
            cols:4

            Button: 
                text: "law"
                font_name: "msyhl.ttc"
                
                on_press:
                    root.Article_Catagory = "1"
                    root.HomepageContent = "home page 2"
                    root.ChangeCatagory_GetArticle_TitleList()
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "ArticleTitle"

            Button:
                text: "paten"
                font_name: "msyhl.ttc"

                on_press:
                    root.Article_Catagory = "2"                
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "ArticleTitle"

            Button:
                text: "logo"
                font_name: "msyhl.ttc"

                on_press:
                    root.Article_Catagory = "3"
                on_release:       
                    app.root.current = "ArticleTitle"
            
            Button:
                text: "others"
                font_name: "msyhl.ttc"

                on_press:
                    root.Article_Catagory = "4"
                    root.ChangeCatagory_GetArticle_TitleList()
                on_release:       
                    app.root.current = "ArticleTitle"



<ArticleTitleWindow>:
    name: "ArticleTitle"

    GridLayout:

        cols:1
    

        GridLayout:

            cols:1

            Button:
                ###the button text doesn't change at all while the variable has changed###
                text: str(root.Article_Titles_List_py[0])
                font_name: "msyhl.ttc"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "Article" 

            Button:
                ###the button text doesn't change at all while the variable has changed###
                text: str(root.Article_Titles_List_py[0])
                font_name: "msyhl.ttc"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "Article" 

            Button:
                text: str(root.Article_Titles_List_py[0])
                font_name: "msyhl.ttc"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "Article" 

            Button:
                text: str(root.Article_Titles_List_py[0])
                font_name: "msyhl.ttc"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "Article" 

            Button:
                text: str(root.Article_Titles_List_py[0])
                font_name: "msyhl.ttc"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "Article" 


        Button:
            text: "Go Back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "Homepage"

<ArticleWindow>:
    name: "Article"

    GridLayout:

        cols:1

        GridLayout:

            cols:2

            Label:
                ###the label text doesn't change at all while the variable has changed###
                text: root.ArticleContent    

            Button:
                text: "Auther"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "Auther"


        Button:
            text: "Go Back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "Homepage"

<AutherWindow>:
    name: "Auther"

    GridLayout:

        cols:1

        Label:
            text: "Auther"    

        Button:
            text: "Go Back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "Homepage"
```

Here is our py file :

```
import requests 

def get_article_counter_list_by_catagories(catagory_number):

    response = requests.get("http://*.*.*.*/pikohelp_article/")
    data = response.json()
    data_amount = data["count"]
    article_counter_list_for_catagory = []

    for article_counter in range (data_amount):

        if data["results"][article_counter]["class_name"][-2] == catagory_number: 

            article_counter_list_for_catagory.append(article_counter)

    return article_counter_list_for_catagory

def get_article_title_by_catagories(article_counter_list_for_catagory):

    response = requests.get("http://*.*.*.*/pikohelp_article/")
    data = response.json()
    data_amount = data["count"]
    title_list_for_catagory = []

    for article_counter in article_counter_list_for_catagory:

        title_list_for_catagory.append(data["results"][article_counter]["title"])

    return title_list_for_catagory











import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class HomepageWindow(Screen):

    Article_Catagory = "1"
    HomepageContent = StringProperty("home page 0")

    def ChangeCatagory_GetArticle_TitleList(self):


        print("test article catagory number")
        print(self.Article_Catagory)

        article_counter_list_for_catagory = get_article_counter_list_by_catagories(self.Article_Catagory)
    
        Article_Titles_List_py = get_article_title_by_catagories(article_counter_list_for_catagory)       
        

        ### the list and string variable is successfully changed ###
        print("test article catagory title list")
        print(Article_Titles_List_py)
        print(ArticleTitleWindow.Article_Titles_List_py)
        ArticleTitleWindow.Article_Titles_List_py = Article_Titles_List_py
        print(ArticleTitleWindow.Article_Titles_List_py)
        
        print("test article content")
        print(ArticleWindow.ArticleContent)
        ArticleWindow.ArticleContent = Article_Titles_List_py
        print(ArticleWindow.ArticleContent)
        ### the list and string variable is successfully changed ###


        return Article_Titles_List_py

    pass    


class ArticleTitleWindow(Screen):

    Article_Titles_List_py = ["","","","",""]

    pass

class ArticleWindow(Screen):

    ArticleContent = StringProperty("test")

    pass


class AutherWindow(Screen):

    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):

    pass



kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")

class MyApp(App):
    
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

In method `ChangeCatagory_GetArticle_TitleList` you need to change the attr. of the instance (of `ArticleTitleWindow`) that has been added to the `root`, not that of the class.

Thus change

```py
ArticleTitleWindow.Article_Titles_List_py = Article_Titles_List_py
```

to

```py
self.manager.get_screen("ArticleTitle").Article_Titles_List_py = Article_Titles_List_py
```

Also change

```
Article_Titles_List_py = ["","","","",""]
```

to

```
Article_Titles_List_py = ListProperty(["","","","",""])
```